# Template injection causing var to be undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in the process of switching from straight javascript to jQuery to handle the different instances of the my timer on the same page. I'm still learning the fundamentals of both languages and have found myself stumped on this. When I create a new timer, enter the values, and then press start its telling me that timer is not defined within the create seconds function, but its logging out in the startTimer function before createSeconds is triggered. What am I missing here? Thanks.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge, chrome=1" />
<title>Kitchen Timer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="timer-css.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Countdown Timer</h1>
  <div id="timers">
  </div>

  <div id="create">
    <button id="createButton">create new timer</button>
  </div>

  <div class="timer_template">
    <div class="inputFields">
      <input class="hours" type="text" value="" name="hours" placeholder="Hours" maxlength="2"> <span>:</span>
      <input class="minutes" type="text" value="" name="min" placeholder="Minutes" maxlength="2"> <span>:</span>
      <input class="seconds" type="text" value="" name="seconds" placeholder="Seconds" maxlength="2">
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <button class="startButton">Start</button>
      <button class="resetButton hidden">Reset</button>
      <button class="pauseButton hidden">Pause</button>
    </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="application/javascript">

  var hourIn = document.querySelector(".hours");
  var minuteIn = document.querySelector(".minutes");
  var secondsIn = document.querySelector(".seconds");
  var startButton = document.querySelector(".startButton");
  var resetButton = document.querySelector(".resetButton");
  var pauseButton = document.querySelector(".pauseButton");
  var inputs = ['.hours', '.minutes', '.seconds'];
  var seconds;
  var interval;
  var running = false;
  startButton.addEventListener("click", startTimer);
  pauseButton.addEventListener("click", pauseTimer);
  resetButton.addEventListener("click", resetTimer);




  var $timer = $('.timer_template');
  var createNew = document.getElementById("createButton");

  createNew.addEventListener('click', function() {
    $timer.clone(true, true).toggleClass('timer_template timer').appendTo("#timers");
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.startButton', function(e) {
    // e.target is the button we click on.
    // e is the event and calling .target get's the thing that was clicked on
    var $this = $(e.target);
    var $this_timer = $this.parents('.timer');
    startTimer($this_timer);
  });

 // input fields only accept numbers
  // document.querySelector(".inputFields").addEventListener("keypress", function (evt) {
  //   if (evt.which < 48 || evt.which > 57)
  //   {
  //     evt.preventDefault();
  //   }
  // });

  function startTimer(timer) {
    // console.log(timer)
    console.log(timer.find('.hours').val())
    console.log(timer.find('.minutes').val())
    console.log(timer.find('.seconds').val())
    if (timer.find('.hours').val() == '' && timer.find('.minutes').val() == '' && timer.find('.seconds').val() == '') {
      alert("Enter a time to begin");
    } else if (!timer.hasClass('running')) {
      timer.addClass('');
      doCountDown();
      toggleInputs(inputs, true);
      showHide();
    }
  }

  function showHide() {
    resetButton.classList.toggle("hidden");
    pauseButton.classList.toggle("hidden");
    startButton.classList.toggle("hidden");
  }

  // Toggle input fields from disabled to enabled
  // @params Array, Boolean
  function toggleInputs(elements,toggle) {
    if (toggle) {
      return elements.forEach(function (elem) {
      document.querySelector(elem).setAttribute('disabled', toggle);
      });
      } else {
        return elements.forEach(function (elem) {
        document.querySelector(elem).removeAttribute('disabled', toggle);
        });
      }
  }

  function createSeconds() {
    console.log(secondsIn)
    seconds = parseInt(timer.find('.seconds').val() || 0) + (parseInt(timer.find('.minutes').val() || 0) * 60) + (parseInt(timer.find('.hours').val() || 0) * 3600);
  }

  function resetTimer() {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    running = false;
    emptyString();
    alertDisplay.textContent = '';
    toggleInputs(inputs, false);
    showHide();
  }

  function pauseTimer() {
    if (running) {
      window.clearInterval(interval);
      running = false;
      pauseButton.textContent = "Continue";
    } else {
      running = true;
      doCountDown();
      pauseButton.textContent = "Pause";
    }
  }

  function doCountDown() {
    createSeconds();
    interval = setInterval(watchCountDown, 1000);

  }

  function watchCountDown() {
    seconds--;
    if (seconds < 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);

      timerAlert();
    } else {
      var h = parseInt(parseInt(seconds / 60) / 60) % 24;
      var m = parseInt(seconds / 60) % 60;
      var s = parseInt(seconds) % 60;
      hourIn.value = h;
      minuteIn.value = m;
      secondsIn.value = s;

    }
  }

  function timerAlert() {
    toggleInputs(inputs, false);
    running = false;
    showHide();
  }

  function emptyString() {
    hourIn.value = '';
    minuteIn.value = '';
    secondsIn.value = '';
  }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a variable in javascript, it needs to be either passed in as an argument to the function (e.g. `function createSeconds(timer) {`), or declared (e.g. `var timer = foo;`) in that function's scope or in an outer scope. In your case, you're neither passing in `timer` as an argument nor declaring it in `createSeconds` or an outer scope.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Emmett, I'm still having a hard time understanding why the startTimer function is able to use 'timer' but createSecond can not? I tried passing 'timer' into createSecond as an argument but it is still throwing an error; "Cannot read property 'find' of undefined". I think there is something simple I'm just not getting here.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, and you were correct. I had to pass timer into all the functions when they were called. Took a while for it to click, but it's working now, I was also able to remove all the global variables when I finished adding jQuery. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, jQuery isn't finding an element in your click handler function:

```
var $this_timer = $this.parents('.timer');
```

It looks like the parent class should be .timer_template.